# How to restart a program in ubuntu using cron?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron, pkill

I'd like to restart a program regardless of it already running or not using crontab.

I have this in crontab -e

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/pkill -f myapp; /home/ubuntu/xyz/bin/res.sh
```

And in the res.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/pkill -f myapp

sleep 10

/home/ubuntu/xyz/bin/myapp & &>/dev/null
```

The problem is if the program is running, it kills the program. but it fails to start the program again.

I don't want to use any condition as to check if the program is already running and start only if it's not.

EDIT: The program is not a service to use "/etc/init.d/service restart" or "sudo service myapp restart"

Thanks.

Comment: You should redirect output to a log file instead of throwing it away, so you can see what happens.

Comment: I already tried to redirect the output but the file is empty, it's same case when using 'nohup'

Comment: The [cron tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info) has a great debugging instructions. Have you tried all of these?

Comment: Don't you think It should be `* * * * * /usr/bin/pkill -f myapp; sh /home/ubuntu/xyz/bin/res.sh`

Comment: @BenjaminW. I did check that thread but am not sure what I missed. arun pal I tried that option too, no success.

Comment: For one, the `&` operator is equivalent to a `;` in that it ends a statement, so your command is equivalent to `myapp; &>/dev/null`. Do not put it anywhere but the end of a statement.